# How to write a Java boolean compare method

Tags: java, boolean, comparator

I need some assistance with Java. How to write a boolean compare method to return true if int a = int b else false. Would it be something like this:

```
public int checkIfEqual(int a, int b) {
  if (int a = int b) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  } 
}
```

Comment: If a == b, you should return 0.  There are three value in a Java `compare`: -1, 0, +1.

Comment: A boolean compare method that return true if the values are the same, and false otherwise? What you're describing is the `equals()` method. For *primitives*, it is done using the `==` equality operator: `public static boolean equals(int a, int b) { return a == b; }`

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to **compare** to int values, then put `a == b` or `a > b` right there in your code. Otherwise think up a more telling method name than "compare". Like areBothNumbersEqual() or something like that.

Comment: I modified the question to be more specific. I apologize for the broadness of the question. Please let me know if my edits are sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
public boolean compare(int a, int b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

---

I notice you were trying to return an `int`: Java ain't C, so some of the C idioms like `0` is false, non-zero is `true` don't hold in Java.

Also, such a method is worse than useless, because:

- `if (a == b)` is shorter to write than `if (compare(a, b))`
- `if (a == b)` is clearer than `if (compare(a, b))`
- `compare()` is practically a reserved word, because it's the (only) method of the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface, a very commonly used class
- `compare` is a poor name, both for the previous reason, but also because `equals` is what it's really doing and is the java convention

Answer (score 1):

As @Bohemian says, if you just want to test if two int values are equal:

```
public boolean equal(int a, int b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

Don't call this method `compare`, because the name `compare` has *strong connotations* of a testing an ordering ... in Java.  Whether it should be `equal` or `equals` is debatable.

(And @Bohemian's point about the above method being useless are apropos.)

---

This is what a proper compare method that implements `int compare(int, int)` should look like<sup>1</sup>.

```
public int compare(int a, int b) {
   if (a == b) {
      return 0;
   } else if (a < b) {
      return -1;
   } else {
      return 1;
   } 
}
```

This is compatible with the semantics of `Comparator::compare(T, T)`.

---

> I also am not sure how to add the following constraints as well:
>
> 0 ≤ a, b ≤ 10000000

Add `if` statements like this:

```
 if (a < 0 || b > 10000000) {
     throw SomeException("some message");
 }
```

where `SomeException` is the exception you are suppose to throw to indicate a constraint error.

---

> Also, do I need to create a checker class that implements the comparator interface as well?

There is no specific reason that a checker class should implement `Comparator`.  Only do it if your checker needs to be *used* as a comparator.

---

> Would this also work the same for strings with the following constraints:
>
> 1 ≤ |a|, |b| ≤ 2000

This **approach** would work for constraining the lengths of the string.

---

<sup>1 - It is quicker to show you the code than to explain what was wrong with your version.  But compare them ... and you should be able to work that out.</sup>

Comment: To compare strings, would I be able to use the following:

    `public boolean compare(String s1, String s20 { return s1==s2); }`

Comment: @mateo  - That is an incorrect implementation.  The correct implementation is `public boolean compare(String s1, String s2) { return s1.equals(s2); }`.  Or to just use `String::equals(Object)`.   Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832

Answer (score -1):

> I need some assistance with Java and how to write a boolean compare method to return true if int a = int b and false otherwise

a == b

a.Equals(b) (Integer class)

b.Equals(a) (Integer class)

a-b == 0

b-a == 0

I think is enough for equality check.

Now for the others checks... add if's with && `(a>x && a<y && b>x && b<y)`

Edit: not use int as boolean value. This is not C (where 0 is false and !=0 is true), bool is a bool, int is a int.

Comment: This is Java, there is no `a.Equals(b)`

Comment: @Andreas Integer.Equals, but right, i must be specific, Thanks

Comment: No such thing as `Integer.Equals` either, and question is specifically abut `int` values, not `Integer` values.